# Listbox multi select in asp.net web forms

Tags: multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have been researching for multiple select in a dropdown list in asp.net web forms. I have found several solutions but when I implement it on my system, it does not work. I am using Visual Studio 2019 by the way.

Here is my sample:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function () {
             $('[id*=listItemBox]').multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true
             });
         });

    </script>

<asp:ListBox ID="listItemBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

This is the output of above.

[image]

But I want to do it like this

[image]

All answers I have been seeing are the same with my work above. But I do not know why it's not working in my end.

Thank in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$('[id*=listItemBox]').multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true
             });
```

To

```
$('[id*=<%= listItemBox.ClientID %>]').multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true
             });
```

As ASP.NET can change element Id sometimes.
To debug `console.log($('[id*=<%= listItemBox.ClientID %>]'))`

Comment: Nothing changed. Still  the same output.

Comment: What is the output of console.log($('[id*=<%= ListBox1.ClientID %>]'))

Comment: is there a console.log in asp.net? Sorry, I do not know. When I put the console.log it appears as text that is being shown in the browser. Not in the console when i press f12

Comment: ASP.NET send text to browser then Multiselect will work.. Just discovered a type in my answer.. please try `$('[id*=<%= listItemBox.ClientID %>]').multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true
             });` instead of `$('[id*=listItemBox]').multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true
             });` and let me know

Comment: Still the same output. Nothing changed.

Comment: Inspect the listbox using chrome and send me its HTML content

Comment: any updates to this? Even I am facing the same problem